# error in fragment activity context

Tags: android

i have an error with my program about context,,,
i will combine navigation draw and list view, but any error with my code,

this is my fragment home activity

```html
package com.marimuncak.mari_muncak;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatCallback;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.marimuncak.mari_muncak.adapter.CustomListAdapter;
import com.marimuncak.mari_muncak.app.AppController;
import com.marimuncak.mari_muncak.module.Jarak;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;





/**
 * Created by azoel on 6/8/2017.
 */
public class Home extends Fragment implements LocationListener,
        SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

    private Context baseContext;

    public Home(){}
    RelativeLayout view;

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
    ListView list;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;
    List<Jarak> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    Double latitude, longitude;
    Criteria criteria;
    Location location;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;

    private static final String url = "https://marimuncak.000webhostapp.com/haversine.php?lat=";
    private static final String TAG = Home.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

        list    = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        swipe   = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe);

        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter (getActivity(), itemList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        criteria = new Criteria();

        getActivity().setTitle("Home");

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh(){
        lokasi();
    }

    // fungsi ngecek lokasi GPS device pengguna
    private void lokasi(){
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        // permintaan update lokasi device dalam waktu 10 detik
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000, 1, this);

        if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);
            callListVolley(latitude, longitude);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Lokasi device pengguna tidak ditemukan.\nMohon hidupkan GPS.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           /* latitude longitude Alun-alun Demak sebagai default jika tidak ditemukan lokasi dari device pengguna */
            callListVolley(-6.894796, 110.638413);
        }
    }

    // untuk menampilkan lokasi wisata terdekat dari device pengguna
    private void callListVolley(double lat, double lng) {
        itemList.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        swipe.setRefreshing(true);

        JsonArrayRequest jArr = new JsonArrayRequest(url + lat +"&lng="+ lng,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Jarak j = new Jarak();
                                j.setNama(obj.getString("nama"));
                                j.setGambar(obj.getString("gambar"));

                                double jarak = Double.parseDouble(obj.getString("jarak"));

                                j.setJarak(""+round(jarak, 2));

                                itemList.add(j);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // memberitahu adapter jika ada perubahan data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        swipe.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        // menambah permintaan ke queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jArr);
    }



    // untuk menyederhanakan angka dibelakan koma jarak
    public static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
        value = value * factor;
        long tmp = Math.round(value);
        return (double) tmp / factor;
    }

    // untuk menentukan lokasi gps dari device pengguna
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // untuk melihat latitude longitude posisi device pengguna pada logcat ditemukan atau tidak
        Log.d(TAG, " "+ latitude +", "+longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    public Context getBaseContext() {

        return baseContext;
    }
}
```

this is a logchat

```html
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
D:\Users\azoel\AndroidStudioProjects\Mari_Muncak\app\src\main\java\com\marimuncak\mari_muncak\Home.java
Error:(94, 48) error: incompatible types: Home cannot be converted to Context
Error:(95, 89) error: incompatible types: Home cannot be converted to Context
D:\Users\azoel\AndroidStudioProjects\Mari_Muncak\app\src\main\java\com\marimuncak\mari_muncak\MainActivity.java
Error:(131, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Note: D:\Users\azoel\AndroidStudioProjects\Mari_Muncak\app\src\main\java\com\marimuncak\mari_muncak\MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1 mins 23.688 secs
Information:4 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

What should I do?
thanks a lot if you help me,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead. you use `android.app.Fragment`

second at this line

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

change to

```
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

third, at line 131 make sure `void onResponse(JSONArray response)` exist at `Response.Listener` interface. i never use volley, so i don't know correct method.

Comment: in SO we must be use universal language, does my answer worked? mark as answer if it's work.